# How to get output values from a MS SQL stored procedure using PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlsrv

I have the following stored procedure on my MS SQL server:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE checkFollowing 
(
    @myMemberID INT,
    @otherMemberID INT
)
AS
BEGIN

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Followers WHERE follower = @myMemberID AND followed = @otherMemberID)
    RETURN 1
ELSE
    RETURN 0    
END 
GO
```

In my PHP code I have this method so far:

```
function iAmFollowing($mymemberID, $otherMemberID) {
    $query = "EXEC checkFollowing @myMemberID = ?, @otherMemberID = ?";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($this->con, $query, array(&$mymemberID, &$otherMemberID));
    $result = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt);

    return $result[0];
}
```

As I have realised now, is that I can't get return values with the sqlsrv_fetch_array() command. But I canøt seem to figure out how to fetch the outpur value using php.
Does someone know how to achieve this?

Any help will be gratly appreciated.

**SOLUTION**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE checkFollowing 
(
    @myMemberID INT,
    @otherMemberID INT
)
AS
BEGIN

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Followers WHERE follower = @myMemberID AND followed = @otherMemberID)
    SELECT 1 AS 'output'
ELSE
    SELECT 0 AS 'output'    
END 
GO
```

And the php code should be almost the same. Just change the return value to: 
   $result['output'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `OUTPUT parameter` in your SP's parameter list. The `OUTPUT parameter` return data back to the calling application. check this **[Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378108(v=sql.110).aspx)** for more info

```
CREATE PROCEDURE checkFollowing 
(
    @myMemberID INT,
    @otherMemberID INT,
    @output INT OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Followers WHERE follower = @myMemberID AND followed = @otherMemberID)
    SELECT @output= 1
ELSE
    SELECT @output= 0    
END 
GO
```

**Update:**

To Call the SP and to store the Output. Try something like this

```
DECLARE @appout int; -- variable to hold the data returned by SP.

EXEC checkFollowing 10,20, @output = @appout OUTPUT; -- This is how i will call a SP.

@appout - will hold the data returned by the procedure.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So when I try to run it with:
"EXEC checkFollowing @memMymberID = ???, \@otherMemberID = ???;"It returns nothing. Do you know what's worng?

Comment: @user68621 _ am not familiar with `PHP` coding. Am just TSQL guy. Check my answer thats how i will call a SP with Output parameter.

Comment: Ahh okay. your solution is working when i run it in mssql management studio, but I also need to make my PHP code retrive the output parameter. But I appreciate your help so far :)

Comment: I found out how to solve this a little different. But what you suggested, was also a solution to the problem (the SQL part anyway). So I'll accept your answer. Thanks for your help!